# Compiling program for old kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel, version, glibc

I statically compiled and linked a program in an up-to-date Linux machine, and ran it in another Linux which is 9 years old. It gave me an error "FATAL: kernel too old" and quit. Specifically, the new one is Fedora 18 (gcc 4.7.2, glibc 2.16, kernel 3.7.2) and the old one is RHEL4.8 (glibc 2.3.4, kernel 2.6.9). Since it's static linking, glibc version shouldn't matter. I guess the problem here is that the program calls system calls that's not in the old kernel.

If development on the old system is not an option, how can I build the program in the new system and run in the older (or even better, both)? I was looking for a way to run gcc in a compatible mode, which only calls old system calls. No luck yet.

Comment: Get an old version of glibc and link against it. New glibc will not run on old kernels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest option is to always build on the older system.

Alternatively, copy the glibc headers and static libraries from the old system to the new and link against those.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to rebuild glibc with `--enable-kernel=2.6.9` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. If I rebuild glibc with enable-kernel, do I have to rebuild all other libraries, such as libjpeg, with that glibc? In other words, can my custom glibc link with stock libjpeg?

Comment: I don't believe so. I think that flag merely adjusts the backend use of system calls, but you're still using the same C library. You might find that the latest C library only supports kernels after some date though, so you might need to downgrade to an older version to go back that far. I wouldn't recommend installing the older library as you system library. Just put it where you can link against it for your build (you'll need some custom compiler flags).